# Creating a form entry calculator with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to build a calculator using form entries as the figures to be calculated and returned to corresponding form fields in another field set. I am fairly new to jQuery and I am following the advice of a book but I must be honest, I do need to rush this a bit and I'm having some problems.

Here is the jfiddle if you need to visualise it: http://jsfiddle.net/u3xx4ubv/14/

EDIT: Not sure on the appropriate form action for this, which may be causing some problems.

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" method="get" id="ATSCalc">
<fieldset>
    <legend>Return on Investment Calculator</legend>
    <label for="aptsBooked" class="label">Avg. Appointments Booked</label>
    <input name="aptsBooked" type="text" id="aptsBooked">
    <br />
    <label for="aptsAttended" class="label">Avg. Appointments Attended</label>
    <input name="aptsAttended" type="text" id="aptsAttended">
    <br />
    <label for="reqMeetings" class="label">Meetings per deal</label>
    <input name="reqMeetings" type="text" id="reqMeetings">
    <br />
    <label for="orderVal" class="label">Avg. order value</label>
    <input name="reqMeetings" type="text" id="reqMeetings">
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</fieldset>
<br />
<fieldset>
    <legend>Results</legend>
    <label for="convRate" class="label">Appointment conversion rate</label>
    <input name="convRate" type="text" id="convRate">
    <br />
    <label for="meetingsPerDeal" class="label">No. of meetings per deal</label>
    <input name="meetingsPerDeal" type="text" id="meetingsPerDeal">
    <br />
    <label for="meetingVal" class="label">Value of each meeting</label>
    <input name="meetingVal" type="text" id="meetingVal">
    <br />
</fieldset>
</form>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#ATSCalc').submit(function(){

var aptsBooked = $('#aptsBooked').val();
var aptsAttended = $('#aptsAttended').val();
var reqMeetings = $('#reqMeetings').val();
var orderVal = $('#orderVal').val();
//Collects values of form input

var aptsConvRate = aptsAttended / aptsBooked * 100;
$('#convRate').val(aptsCovRate); //Outputs meeting conversion rate to form field.

var meetingsPerDeal = aptsBooked / reqMeetings;
$('#meetingsPerDeal').val(meetingsPerDeal); //Outputs meeting per deal value to form field.

var meetingVal = orderVal / meetingsPerDeal;
$('#meetingVal').val(meetingVal); //Outputs value of each meeting to form field.
//Variables for calculation of Return on Investment figures
                     }}; // end submit()
                     }}; // end ready ()
```

I am trying to run the second group of variables and return the outputs in the fields seen in the second fieldset. I imagine it is just syntax errors or misplaced code but I am really struggling to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/u3xx4ubv/18/)

You missed

- `}};` instead of `});` as your closing brackets
- variable name *aptsCovRate* instead of `aptsConvRate` ( missing `n` )

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#ATSCalc').submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        var aptsBooked =  parseInt($('#aptsBooked').val(), 10);
        var aptsAttended = parseInt($('#aptsAttended').val(), 10);
        var reqMeetings = parseInt($('#reqMeetings').val(), 10); 
        var orderVal = parseFloat($('#orderVal').val());
        //Collects values of form input

        var aptsConvRate = aptsAttended / aptsBooked * 100;

        $('#convRate').val(aptsConvRate); //Outputs meeting conversion rate to form field.
                            /* ^^^^ Conv !! not Cov */

        var meetingsPerDeal = aptsBooked / reqMeetings;
        $('#meetingsPerDeal').val(meetingsPerDeal); //Outputs meeting per deal value to form field.

        var meetingVal = orderVal / meetingsPerDeal;
        $('#meetingVal').val(meetingVal); //Outputs value of each meeting to form field.
        //Variables for calculation of Return on Investment figures
    }); // end submit()
}); // end ready ()
```

Also, it would be good to use `parseInt()` (value to integer <sup>[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)</sup>) with radix parameter and `parseFloat()` (value to floating-point number <sup>[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)</sup>) methods while getting your Number values from your inputs.

To round your results take a look at the `toFixed()` method.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things wrong with your javascript/HTML, and a few things you missed.

1. `$('#convRate').val(aptsCovRate);` should be `$('#convRate').val(aptsCo**n**vRate);`
2. The end submit and end ready should be `});` not `}};`
3. You do not have a HTML input with `orderVal` as an ID.  It needs to be changed.

Finally, what you missed - your form will submit and refresh and you'll lose the calculated values.  You can fix this by using `e.stopPropagation();` and `e.preventDefault();`

Updated fiddle should be working for you: http://jsfiddle.net/u3xx4ubv/17/